# NestJs: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs

i have a problem with connecting to database in nest.js with typeorm and postgres.

I created a **.env file** in the root project directory with the following content

```
POSTGRES_HOST=127.0.0.1
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DATABASE=db-name
```

In the **app.module.ts** I writed the code below:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { FeedModule } from './feed/feed.module';

  @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: parseInt(<string>process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    FeedModule,
  ],
  
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But when im running the app by npm start it throws this error: `new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NestJs you should use ConfigService to get environment variables inside your typeorm module, read the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) for more information.

You can use it like that:

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`
    ),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      injects: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: configService.get("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        port: configService.get("POSTGRES_PORT"),
        username: configService.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
        password: configService.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        database: configService.get("POSTGRES_DB"),
        entities: [],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#async-configuration), you can define a factory function where you inject the config-service allowing you to resolve the corresponding values:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    port: +configService.get<number>('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DATABASE'),
    synchronize: true,
    autoLoadEntities: true,
  }),
  inject: [ConfigService],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by using the config module.

Just do `npm i @nestjs/config`. Then in the imports array just above the TypeOrmModule put `ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),`. This allows your module to get the environment variables from the `.env` file

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I put the .env file inside the src by mistake. If you put it outside of the src it will fix it

Comment: as trivial as it gets...this was the cause of my problem!
Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and it was weird because I modified several times that configuration just to check if "something new happens" but have no success.

Long story short, I deleted the "dist" folder of the project and build the app again (`npm run build`) and it worked! It appeared that I had a "bad build" running over and over again so this workaround kind of "refreshed" the build and let things running well again.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

If all the previous answers haven't worked, make sure that your ".env" file is named as such and not something like ".env2" or similar